# Does the failover is automatically in AAD itself

Tags: azure, point, failover

Our service will use AAD in any of 56 Azure regions, does AAD service regional? Will we face single point Failure problem?
And in case AAD live site in any region/or globally, how should an application to react to mitigate? Or does the failover is automatically in AAD itself?

Comment: AAD/B2C is a global resource using the Microsoft SSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely have no reason to worry about failover for AAD.

From documentation:

### Redundancy:

For durability, any piece of data written to Azure AD is replicated to at least 4 and up to 13 datacenters depending on your tenant configuration. Within each data center, data is again replicated at least 9 times for durability but also to scale-out capacity to serve authentication load. To illustrate—this means that at any point in time, there are at least 36 copies of your directory data available within our service in our smallest region. For durability, writes to Azure AD are not completed until a successful commit to an out of region datacenter.

As mentioned, Azure AD itself is architected with multiple levels of internal resilience, but our principle extends even further to have resilience in all our external dependencies. This is expressed in our no single point of failure (SPOF) principle.

### No single point of failure.

Given the criticality of our services we don’t accept SPOFs in critical external systems like Distributed Name Service (DNS), content delivery networks (CDN), or Telco providers that transport our multi-factor authentication (MFA), including SMS and Voice. For each of these systems, we use multiple redundant systems configured in a full active-active configuration.

### Elastically scales

Azure AD is already a massive system running on over 300,000 CPU Cores and able to rely on the massive scalability of the Azure Cloud to dynamically and rapidly scale up to meet any demand. This can include both natural increases in traffic, such as a 9AM peak in authentications in a given region, but also huge surges in new traffic served by our Azure AD B2C which powers some of the world’s largest events and frequently sees rushes of millions of new users.

Comment: Thanks Serhii. In fact, our goal is to ensure one region down, but AAD should be still alive which means it is regional redundancy.